# Create a Powershell command to move a folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with some other folders inside and a file inside and I want to **move it** to `%programdata%` folder.

I am new to this and not sure how to do this?

Comment: but I really have to point out that this is a bad question, you should probably do at least some research upfront

Answer (score 2):

```
Move-Item -Path path_to_your_folder -Destination c:\ProgramData
```

or you could substitute `C:\ProgramData` with `$Env:ProgramData`

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/Move-Item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: And the full Powershell Reference for the Move-Item command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/Move-Item